# Simple Twig IF statement with variable in Symfony2

Tags: symfony, twig

I'm trying to only include some HTML based on an IF statement:

```
{% if "{{ app.request.attributes.get('var_name') }}" != "" %}
<meta id="var_name" content="{{ app.request.attributes.get('var_name') }}" />
{% endif %}
```

The above will work exactly as expected if the var_name variable holds data, but if it is empty or not defined it always returns the HTML like this:

```
<meta id="var_name" content="" />
```

...so basically it is registering the IF statement as true, even though there's nothing to show.

It makes no difference if the variable is defined or not.

Also, this:

```
{% if {{ app.request.attributes.get('var_name') }} != "" %}
```

...returns this error:

A hash key must be a quoted string, a number, a name, or an expression enclosed in parentheses (unexpected token "punctuation" of value "{" in...

How do I do it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do this:

```
{% if app.request.attributes.get('var_name') != "" %}
```

You don't need the `{{ }}` inside the `{% %}`

More info: [Twig - IF](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/if.html)

Comment: Perfect. Simple when you know how! Thanks. I'll accept answer in 5 mins when it allows.